# Detect a point inside a 3D box

Tags: c#, math

I have a 3D Shape made from 2 Cylinders:

[image]

The dots (black and white) are origins of the circular ends on each cylinder. I would like to get 3 points (white dots) so I need to detect and exclude a point that inside a cylinder (black dot). How can I detect it!

Edit: I have the bounding box of each cylinder.

Comment: Do you want to test for the bounding box, or the cylinder itself?

Answer (score 0):

Put a coordinate system on the end of the cylinder (say laying along the *x*-axis). To test if a point *A* is inside the cylinder (with length *L* and radius *R*), do the following

```
if( y^2+z^2 <= R^2 && x>=0 && x<=L )
{
   // point (x,y,z) is inside cylinder
}
```

To use the above you need to transform the coordinates of the point `(x_A,y_A,z_A)` to the local coordinates of the cylinder `(x,y,z)`. You need to provide more information on how the cylinders are defined in 3D in order to show an example of how to do this. I am hoping since you are doing 3D programming, that you are familiar with 3D rotations and know some basic geometry.

---

Alternative approach would be to eliminate the point that is nearest to the cylinder axis. Look at [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points) on how to get the distance of a point to a line.

Comment: the shape is an object in unity3D ! Yes, it have rotation, transform.